# Error getting when try to installing font awesome free

Tags: angular, npm, font-awesome

I have get below error

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="https://npm.fontawesome.com/",service="npm.fontawesome.com"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Samanthika\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-11T23_51_19_635Z-debug.log
```

In previous project I have mistakenly do the global configuration using below commands

```
npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/

npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" TOKEN

@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=TOKEN
```

I cannot install fontawesome to my new projects after do the global config bacause it gives same error.
How I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you change the TOKEN Word, for the real generated token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, run the following command to delete the old registry.

```
npm config delete "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/
```

Then install the required package to your project

```
npm install / npm install "package name"
```

This should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can simply include Font Awsome CDN in the index.html file.

Go to https://fontawesome.com/start and enter your email in the given field. You will receive an email with the CDN URL and include that in the header part of the index.html.